# How Do I Get A Child Record ID Into The Master Record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, related-list, iframe

[image]
Currently i'm using this simple iframe to show a visualforce page built on a custom object called Paperwork__c which is a child relationship to Apprentice__c where I currently have it displaying.

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true" title="Title" standardController="Apprentice__c">
    <iframe height="1850px" id="theIframe" name="theIframe" src="/apex/Checklist?id=a0L1t000000IUf6EAG" width="100%"></iframe>
</apex:page>
```

But what I need is to update the record id on the iframe link to the corresponding paperwork__c.Id. E.G /apex/Checklist?id={PaperworkRecordId}.

How do I make this link dynamic and set the correct related child ID?

If more information is required I can provide. Been stumped for ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parent record may have more than one child (in theory, at least). The most appropriate way would be to use the child relationship name and iterate over the list:

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true" title="Title" standardController="Apprentice__c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!Apprentice__c.Paperwork__r}" var="paperwork">
    <iframe height="1850px" id="theIframe" name="theIframe" src="/apex/Checklist?id={!paperwork.Id}" width="100%"></iframe>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

You'll find the correct relationship name in the Paperwork__c object on the Apprentice__c lookup field definition.